# I have this bash script but how can I improve to get a finish exit?

Tags: shell-script

Hi I am new to bash scripts and I have the code bellow and it runs without any error or finish exit. I would like to add a line to stdout a message of failure or exit at the end, just for make sure it worked out or not.
Any of you guys would help me.
Thanks
PS- if possible help to get more generic to.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
fastq-dump --split-files SRR531199
head -n 2000000 SRR531199_1.fastq > SRR531199_1.500k.fastq
head -n 2000000 SRR531199_2.fastq > SRR531199_2.500k.fastq
for dataset in SRR497965 SRR497966 SRR497967 SRR497968 ERR1716491
do
 fastq-dump -M 1000 --table SEQUENCE $dataset
done
```

The code I got from this tutorial at app at end of the site:
http://evomics.org/learning/assembly-and-alignment/2018-assembly-kmer-lab/

Comment: This totally won't work. Please fix up your example by editing the question. All the pipes are missing, for example. Hint: you're looking for `&&` and `||`

Comment: I have put the link and tried to edit the code as it looks at the tutorial. Because this I am trying to get it working, but I am not familiar with bash scripting yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to act on the exit code of a command or script.  In your case since you are looping over several commands it might be best to collect the exit code of each similar to the following:

```
failures=0

fastq-dump --split-files SRR531199
head -n 2000000 SRR531199_1.fastq > SRR531199_1.500k.fastq
head -n 2000000 SRR531199_2.fastq > SRR531199_2.500k.fastq
for dataset in SRR497965 SRR497966 SRR497967 SRR497968 ERR1716491
do
    fastq-dump -M 1000 --table SEQUENCE "$dataset" || ((failures++))
done

if ((failures>=1)); then
    echo "Script had $failures failures"
    exit $failures
else
    exit 0
fi
```

This will add 1 to the `failures` variable for every command in your loop that exits non-zero.  Then it will echo how many failures it counted and exit with that number.

Comment: Using the code as it appears int the site it looks like in a infinite loop. It doesnt show that it worked out. I check for a script to check just like that:

Answer (score 2):

This depends on what you want:

- If you want to check all your `fastq-dump` and `head`-commands separately: Add `&& echo THIS_COMMAND worked || echo THIS_COMMAND failed` on the end of those lines. (replace `THIS_COMMAND` by the command that you tested). You can't use this for the `for`, `do` and `done` but this doesn't make much sense anyway (those are not commands but things that generate the for-loop).
- If you want to check if the script as whole works and immediately want to stop running once something fails then I would do it like this:

  1. Put `|| exit` at the end of every line (again with exceptions for `for`, `do` and `done`)
  2. Put the line `echo everything worked` at the end of the script

Also possible, but less trivial, is a combination:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
fastq-dump --split-files SRR531199 ; if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then echo splitting failed ; exit ; fi
head -n 2000000 SRR531199_1.fastq > SRR531199_1.500k.fastq ; if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then echo first head failed ; exit ; fi
head -n 2000000 SRR531199_2.fastq > SRR531199_2.500k.fastq  ; if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then echo 2nd head failed ; exit ; fi
for dataset in SRR497965 SRR497966 SRR497967 SRR497968 ERR1716491
do
 fastq-dump -M 1000 --table SEQUENCE $dataset ; if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then echo working with $dataset failed ; exit ; fi
done
echo everything worked
```

This stops the script immediately when something fails and tells you what failed. If everything works it also mentions this.

**Be warned**: Every method depends on the fact that a working command exits with returncode 0 and a failing one doesn't. This is the case for most commands on Linux systems (certainly for `head`, but I can't say the same thing for `fastq-dump` for sure)